# Setting up a basic web proxy in apache

Tags: apache, proxy

I'm looking to run Apache as a proxy for web development. I'm running Mac OS X 10.5.4, which already has Apache 2.2.8 installed and running.

I'd like to point my JavaScript files (which are running locally on my machine) to:

```
http://localhost/test.php
```

which would hit the local apache server, then have that apache instance forward to my real remote server:

```
http://www.mysite.com/test.php
```

I've looked at a few walkthroughs but they seem to be out of date. I'm wondering if there's a recent how-to on setting this up - the doc here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html

gives a basic example, but I'm not sure where that text should be added - to http.conf? Do I simply add it there, then restart the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The proxy setup that you describe is called a [Reverse Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy).

This is very easy to set up in Apache, by using the [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) module.

The fundamental mod_proxy directive to set up a reverse proxy is the `ProxyPass`. You would typically add the following line to your local Apache configuration file (usually `httpd.conf` or `apache2.conf`):

```
ProxyPass     /remote/     http://www.mysite.com/
```

In this case, the browser would be requesting `http://localhost/remote/test.php` but your local Apache server would serve this by acting as a proxy to `http://www.mysite.com/test.php`.

You also need to make sure to have the following configuration lines uncommented in your Apache config file:

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Make sure to restart your local Apache service after you do any changes to the config file.

Comment: Don't you have to put ProxyPass within a tag? I can't get apache to start with it outside

Comment: The ProxyPass should be within a <VirtualHost> or a .htaccess file.

Comment: you may want to define some [parameters](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) as well (scroll to the table)

Comment: @ShaunMcDonald `ProxyPass` is not allowed in `.htaccess`: `/srv/www/htdocs/shopwiz/web/.htaccess: ProxyPass not allowed here`.